# Any idea how to pevent a listview displayed in an Android Widget to fliker every time data is refreshed?

Tags: android, android-listview, widget, android-remoteview

I'm displaying a widget with a listview.
When I need to refresh the listview data I'm calling the following code

```
appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(widgetIds, R.id.list);
```

This works fine except that the listview flickers a lot every time this is called. Is there a way to prevent this?

EDIT: After doing a lot of test it looks like the flickering only happens when I display an imageview in the listview rows using the following code

```
view.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.thumbnail, bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reasons using

```
views.setImageViewUri(R.id.thumbnail, uri);
```

instead of

```
view.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.thumbnail, bitmap);
```

fixes the issue. No more flickering when refreshing the listview content of a widget